# Angular push object to array update or add new

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method that adds an object to an array:

```
myarray = [];

<button (click)="addObjToarray({ id: 1, name: 'pat' })">Add</button>

addObjToarray(obj) {
  this.myArray.push(obj);
}
```

I need it to add a new one if the id is not already there or update the existing object if it already exists.

So I would end up with something like this:

```
[
 { id: 1, name: 'pat' },
 { id: 7, name: 'ken' }
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
addObjToarray(obj) {
  let elmIndex = -1;
  const found = this.myarray.some((el, index) => {
    elmIndex = index; 
    return el.id === obj.id;
  })
  if (!found){
    this.myarray.push(obj);
  } else{
    this.myarray[elmIndex] = obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: It complains about this: arr.some

Comment: I get this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Comment: It's not that because I've changed it to: "this.myarray.some" and I'm still getting the error .... variable is: myarray = [];

Comment: Dude the code is correct the error that you are facing is due to wrong naming of a variable or variable that doesn't exist check your code, the logic is correct BTW,
`Cannot read property 'some' of undefined` following error only comes when you are implementing a variable that doesn't exist or the variable Is undefined

Answer (score 1):

## Basic Array Manipulation

You can manipulate an array in JavaScript in various ways, either by writing your own iterative code, or by utilizing the standard methods available on the Array prototype.

[See a list of methods here (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Breaking down your task, we need to do the following:

- Determine if an element is in an array, by the object's id
- add the object if it is not there.
- update the object if it is there.

You already solved the first part of calling `arr.push(obj)` in the negative case, so looking at the positive case, what you need to do is to determine the index of the item you wish to update, and then update the item.

### Determining the index of an element

Looking at the documentation linked above, we can see that there is a method provided which perfectly suits our needs `findIndex()`

So, given we need to both know the index, and check whether to go the positive or negative path our code becomes:

```js
function updateOrPushToArr(obj, arr) {
 const objIndex = arr.findIndex(inArray => inArray.id == obj.id);
 if(objIndex > -1) {
  arr[objIndex] = obj;
 } else {
  arr.push(obj);
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this on it: this.updateOrPushToArr({ id: 1, name: 'pat' }, this.myarray); but adds nothing...any idea?

Comment: I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined